# What's the most efficient way to grind for coins?

Tags: mortal-kombat-11

Most of the customisation items for characters are locked away in the Krypt mode, which requires you to spend coins to open boxes that contain random items. The boxes with the better items are much more expensive than the others and drain resources quickly.

What's the quickest/most efficient way to grind for the coins required to open a bunch of chests for the best chance at getting the items you want?

Note: The in-game store lets you purchase specific items, but it's only about 5 at a time and they're on a rotation that takes many real-world hours to rotate. It's not a viable solution to the problem of getting the items you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

I found quite a few farming methods, online. The two best methods appear to use a combination of augments to farm *other* resources and convert them directly into koin. This is especially useful, as you can remove augments along the conversion path to farm the other resources, as well.

---

### Farming with Frost

I found [this video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/_FtEapEcKYs?t=100) that details a specific build for farming koins with Frost. Using the *"Cold Efficiency"* and *"Snow Piercer"* augments for easy flawless victories, and the *"Perfect Kombat"* augment to reward additional hearts for flawless victories, you can then use the *"Heart and Soul"* and *"Dark Magic"* augments to convert the hearts into koin. The build shown reports that it can earn 2,500,000 koin per second. It might be a grind to unlock the required augments, but it would definitely make grinding all the required koin considerably easier.

### Farming with Krushing Blows

I found this video on YouTube that details creating a build to farm souls by using the *"Pure and Simple"* augment to remove the requirements for krushing blows and the *"Smoke and Mirrors"* augment to remove the limits and damage inflicted by krushing blows. You then use the *"Spirit Collector"* to earn spirits with each krushing blow. With this build, you can set up a match and spam krushing blows to farm souls. By adding the *"Dark Magic"* augment, you can convert the farmed souls straight into koin.

### Sending AI-Controlled Characters into the Endless Tower

I found [this video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/SRlmB3ibvYI), where you send an AI controlled fighter into the endless classic tower. You have to be present to press the confirmation button, between rounds, but you are free to do other things while the AI fighter earns you koin. AI fighters appear to prefer using fatalities and brutalities, so this also earns you hearts.

### Farming the Krypt

I found [this video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/e_2pGkA7eqg?t=742), where you unlock soul fragments by completing character towers, and then go to the Krypt and open as many soul fragment chests as you can. Spend koin to replenish the soul fragment chests, then wash and repeat. You earn more koin than you spend, as well as soul fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh yeah there's no way around the grind, they really wanted you to buy time krystals for convenience. One thing that does help is the tower Cache of Wealth, insanely difficult but it does reward 150k+ depending on how you do. There's also the dailys that you can hit for 30k a day and the weekly race to the top. The race is not guaranteed gold but placing in the top 99% usually hands out 50k there. After that, the only way to maximize is to learn some long combos, as those contribute to your gold immediately and post-game.

Or, if you don't care about playing, just send your AI through some towers while you watch/play something else (you only have to hit x). It's bad, but most of the chests in the krypt don't go over 15k. Also, nobody plays Mortal Kombat here, if you find another forum please let me know.